# What this SQL query in a URL does?

Tags: sql, url

I am trying to understand what this SQL query in a URL does.

http://thewebsite.com/SupplierWeb/Login.jspstatus=3&WFer=4486 AND 1=1 UNION ALL SELECT 1,NULL,'',table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE 2>1--/**/; EXEC xp_cmdshell('cat ../../../etc/passwd')#

Please advise

Comment: Looks like if the website in question is susceptible of SQL Injection (plus other flaky security) you could get the list of tables in the datbase and also the passwords of all users in the server itself.

Comment: As The Impaler indicates, it is a nasty intent of SQL Injection. By doing `AND 1=1 UNION ALL` the rest of the query could be executed. It would try to get the information schema of the tables of your database. Then, it tries to execute a linux/unix command to obtain the file that might contain the usernames and password in your system.

Comment: @acarlstein I think you should post your comment as an answer. You have explained _What this SQL query in a URL does_

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As The Impaler indicated, it is a nasty intent of SQL Injection. By doing `AND 1=1 UNION ALL` the rest of the query could be executed.

It will try to get the information schema of the tables of your database. Then, it will try to execute a linux/unix command to obtain the file that might contain the usernames and password in your system.